# Fetch page with base64 images

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, base64, fetch

I am trying to fetch Google Shopping page with products and I need to get the thumbnails. The problem is that images encoded in base64 and the response contain shortened code in src attribute of images. Instead of full code there is `///////`

```
src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="
```

Here is my code

```
let title = "RockDove Men's Original Two-Tone Memory Foam Slipper";
let urlparse = "https://www.google.com/search?tbm=shop&tbs=vw:g&q=" +
encodeURIComponent(title);

fetch(urlparse)
  .then(data => {
    return data.text();
  })
  .then(htmlString => {
    // parsing html string into DOM
    let parser = new DOMParser();
    let doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");

    // retrieve products data from DOM
    let products = doc.querySelectorAll(".sh-pr__product-results > div");
    let productsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(products);

    let productsData = productsArr.map(el => {
      return el.querySelector(".sh-dgr__thumbnail").innerHTML;
    });
    console.log(productsData);
  });
```

I also tried to use [.blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob) instead of [.text()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) and then [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read from the 
Blob object but result is the same

Comment: `data:image/gif;base64,R` that's known as a data uri, it's not a shortened code, it's actually the image.  You can get that and place on any img & set it's src, your can even place in the Url bar, and the image would appear.  What is it that your wanting to do with the thumbnail?

Comment: it is shortened further with ///// instead of code `...lhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEA...`

Comment: If your using chrome that's just it shortening it for viewing purposes.  If you right click from the inspector in chrome and do `copy link address` you will see the full url.  You can even then paste this into the url bar, and the image will appear.

Comment: I understand it but i need to fetch it with my code and pass it further not just manually see it